# How to treat a PHP image generation script as an image

Tags: php, facebook, dynamically-generated

This is an odd question but I'm stuck on how I would achieve this and I am unable to find any methods of doing so.

I have a simple php script that takes variables (containing file names) from the URL, cleans then and then uses them to generate a single image from the inputted values. This works fine and outputs a new png to the webpage using:

```
imagepng($img);
```

I also have a facebook sharing script in PHP that takes a filepath as an input and then shares the image on the users feed where this statement is used to define the image variable:

```
$photo = './mypic.png'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
```

I don't know how I can link these two together though. I would like to use my generation script as the image to share.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this? I am not the master of PHP so go easy please.

-Tim

## **UPDATE**

If it helps, here are the links to the two pages on my website containing the outputs. They are very ruff mind you:

The php script generating the image:
http://the8bitman.herobo.com/Download/download.php?face=a.png&color=b.png&hat=c.png

The html page with the img tag:
http://the8bitman.herobo.com/Share.html

Comment: You simply share the URL to the image generating script

Comment: But what if my .php file outputted text? How would the API deal with that? The image generation script isn't an image file. It just contains an image within it. Would that work?

Comment: If you set image headers like in the example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), that API will know it's an image

Comment: I already had the image header included. It recognises that is an image but the image is either corrupted, not found or incorrectly formatted.

Comment: oh it seems you just forgot to add `http://` to the image url

Comment: Ah you got it! My hosting company defaults to removing the 'http://' so I copied it without that. That you very much both of you. It works now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it as a simple image:

```
<img src="http://yourserve/yourscript.php?onlyImage=1" />
```

yourscript.php

```
if($_GET['onlyimage']) {
 header('Content-type:image/png'); //or your image content type
 //print only image
} else {
 //print image and text too
}
```

Comment: I tried that. When I go on the php script, the output is the image however when I call the php script as the image source attribute, I just get one of those 'Cannot display image icons'

Comment: I updated my source, you need to specify your content type `header('Content-type:image/png');`

Comment: Already had that in unfortunately. It knows that it is an image. Without that it gets a string of text instead.